# Why is this specific case not possible?

Tags: combinatorics

The problem statement is:

"A woman has written k letters and addressed k envelopes for them. She then randomly puts the letters in the envelopes. Show that the number of letters which are put in the proper envelope can be any number from 0 to k except k — 1."

I don´t know how to deal with this problem. Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: If $k-1$ of the $k$ letters are in their proper envelope, then what can you say about the remaining letter?

Comment: The (slightly) more interesting part is why all other numbers are possible.

Comment: Too many questions begin or end with "I don't even know how to begin with this problem". While this may be true [...], it is still not a valid reason to limit your post to the statement of the problem without any mention of your own thoughts.  – From [Avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/27933/42969).

Answer (score -3, accepted):

First of all see if it makes sense. If I had 5 envelope and I put 4 letters correctly then it’s not possible that last letter is incorrect. Now to generalise this case you can use induction.

1 letter and 1 envelope   Base case
2 letter and 2 envelopes will always be 0 or 2 correct, coz you can be correct in both envelopes or wrong in both.
N letters and N assume it’s correct

N+1 letters and N+1 envelopes assume wrong.

This can be broken into
N letters correct and last 1 wrong
This is not possible....hence the proof.

Comment: This is hardly a proof by induction.  Where do you use the induction hypothesis?  "This can be broken into N letters correct and last 1 wrong. This is not possible....hence the proof."  This says, "The theorem is true; hence the proof."  More like proof by assertion than proof by induction.

Comment: Ok guys, I understood. It's just I misinterpreted the problem. Thanks. And I think saulspatz is right about it is more a proof by assertion.